# issue with graphics on motherboard biostar

Tags: graphics

i am testing right now Ubuntu 13.10 x86 on my old computer but i am having an issue whenever i try to start with Ubuntu,and it gives me an error that says ¨graphics card  could not be detected. you will need to configure these yourself. and it gives me some options

-run in low-graphics mode for just one session

-reconfigure graphics

-troubleshoot the error

-exit to console login

if i choose the first option i got a message that says ¨stay by one minute while the display restarts¨ so i wait for more than 1 minute and i press ok button and after that nothing happen, i have waited for 30 minutes and still nothing happens, so i have to restart the computer

and if i choose exit to console login, nothing happen as well only a black screen, so i have to restart the computer.

and if i try the other 2 options the computer got stuck asking me the same questions

at this time i dont know what to do beacuse i already tried to reinstall ubuntu like 2 times and i also  tried to start ubuntu from the dvd and i always get the same scenario.

my computer

Pentium 4 ht sockect 775 3.0 ghz
1.5 gb ram ddr2
motherboard Biostar p4m800 pro m7
hdd 80 gb ide

i would really appreciate if you can help me out

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

With some searching, it looks like that motherboard has integrated VIA S3 UniChrome graphics. Unfortunately, Linux support looks a bit tricky for those cards.

I found a thread here:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184594

And a bug here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-sis/+bug/1066464

That bug is supposedly fixed, so you can give the new Ubuntu a try (14.04), or try the workaround mentioned on that but with your 13.10 installation.